# fscanf with while loop resulting in double reads per line

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

I'm having some trouble getting fscanf to work properly when reading a text file.

My text file is (there are [spaces] in front of every letter):

```
 L 10,4 
 S 18,4
 L 20,4
 S 28,4
 S 50,4
```

What I want to do is read each line and store the values into some memory. Right now, however, I just want to solve this issue I'm having when using the while loop- I'm getting two outputs per line essentially, and I can't figure out why.

Here is my code:

```
FILE *tFile = fopen(tracefile, "r");
int address, size;
char operation;
char comma;
printf("START \n");
while(fscanf(tFile, "%c %x %c %d", &operation, &address, &comma, &size) > 0){
    printf("O: %c", operation); 
    printf("\n");
    printf("A: %x", address); 
    printf("\n");
    printf("C: %c", comma); 
    printf("\n");
    printf("S: %d", size); 
    printf("\n");

}
printf("END \n");
fclose(tFile);
```

Lastly, my output is

```
START
O:
A: 0
C:
S: 4195731
O: L
A: 10
C: ,
S: 4
O:
A: 10
C: ,
S: 4
O: S
A: 18
C: ,
S: 4
O:

A: 18
C: ,
S: 4
O: L
A: 20
C: ,
S: 4
O:

A: 20
C: ,
S: 4
O: S
A: 28
C: ,
S: 4
O:

A: 28
C: ,
S: 4
O: S
A: 50
C: ,
S: 4
O:

A: 50
C: ,
S: 4
END
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: check the return value of `fscanf`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath He does - that part is fine. It's the format that's slightly wrong.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: it returns the number of input items assigned. I bet you if you print it, you would see surprising results and that clue could lead you to the format problem...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath That's true, the post-condition of `fscanf(...) == 4` is much stronger than that of `fscanf(...) > 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format string needs to match the format of your file precisely, otherwise it's going to read wrong characters into `%c`s.

- Since there are spaces at the beginning of each line, the format needs to have a space there, too
- Since there is no space after the first number and the comma, the format must not have that space either.
- The space after the comma may stay, because `%d` allows leading spaces, but it wouldn't hurt to remove that space either.

This should fix the problem:

```
while(fscanf(tFile, " %c %x%c%d", &operation, &address, &comma, &size) > 0) ...
```

Note: `%x` expects a pointer to an *unsigned int*, so you should change the declaration of `address` to match the expected type.

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/UFJTAK).

Answer (score 0):

you should output a format similar to the one written in the file 
for example you have a line written as `L 10,4` then it should be formated as `%c %d,%d`
so try `fscanf(tFile, " %c %d,%d", &operation, &address, &size)` instead , unless you need the comma then you'll have to use `fscanf(tFile , " %c %d%c%d" , &operation , &address , &comma , &size)` the spaces are important